# hidden environment variables inside chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a chrome extension. Totally new to this.

For the loggin part, I want to post output to a server where I host Elastic.

I have a working set-up through an XMLHttpRequest. Inside the `upLog.open()` I have my credentials to my Elastic environment.

However: I don't want my Elastic credentials hard-coded in my chrome extension.

What is the best way to hide these?

My current function for logging:

```
function sendLog(log){
  let upLog = new XMLHttpRequest();

  upLog.open('POST', 'https://xxxxx.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243/chrome-extension-logging/log_objects/' , true , 'username', 'password' );
  upLog.onload = function (oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.currentTarget.status !== 201) {
      setErrorBadge();
      console.log('Can\'t upload Error Log to service', oEvent.currentTarget.responseText);
      showAlert('Error', 'Can\'t upload Error Log to service');
      return { status: false, data: {} };
    } else {
      console.log('Log uploaded');
      setSuccessBadge();
      showAlert('Success', 'Log uploaded');
      return { status: true, data: {} };
    }
  };
  upLog.onerror = function (oEvent) {
    setErrorBadge();
    console.log('Can\'t upload log to service', oEvent);
    showAlert('Error', 'Can\'t upload log to service (server error)');
    return { status: false };
  };
  upLog.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  upLog.send(JSON.stringify({ item : log }));
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve here? do you want a way where you can set up different ENV variables? or just hide the details of the connection string?

Comment: It would be hiding the credentials. An installed chrome extension can be found on the hard-drive of the user. Ideally, this code does not contain my user credentials of my elastic search environment.

what I did for now was creating a user that can only post "new items" to the elastic search, however, I would prefer even this is not visible in the code.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Streamlining the Sign-in Flow Using Credential Management API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/credential-management-api).

With the use of [Credential Management API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/credential-management-api#what_is_the_credential_management_api), you may enable mediation mode with `navigator.credentials.requireUserMediation()`. As long as the user's mediation status for the origin is turned on, using `unmediated: true` with `navigator.credentials.get()`, that function will resolve with `undefined`.